# Запись файлов в папку при парсинге. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

Как сделать чтобы в папку записывались файлы по возрастанию чисел, например при парсинге... К примеру: Название_сайта01.txt и т.д. пока не закончатся сайты которые записываются в файл.
Это надо сделать на питоне.

Comment: Если не затруднит, то пожалуйста можно пример.

Comment: Что записывается в файлы?

Comment: Записывается в файлы заголовок новости и сама новость(топик), хотя на некоторых страницах с этим проблемы, разные части топиков имеют разные теги, но у всей темы есть один общий тег, но с ним у меня почему-то не получается сделать.

Comment: в коде известно, сколько всего новостей надо записать в файлы?

Comment: Ну вообще нет.. Я могу разве что сказать, что на странице новостей 16 страниц, которые мы можем увидеть, как пользователи... Возможно, если поставить ограничение на страницы. К примеру питон их может увидеть больше, чем 16 страниц, то сделать ограничение в 20 символов. А на каждой странице, по несколько новостей.

Comment: Плюс учитывать надо, что через какое-то время страниц становится все больше, т.к. новости добавляются. Это я к тому, что не разумно будет постоянно следить за количеством новостей чтобы поправить код под новую информацию..

Answer (score 1):

По идее тут простая запись по файлам:

```py
l = ["ya.ru", "google.com", "yandex.ru"]
i = 0
for site in l:
    f_name = "site" + str(i) + ".txt"
    i +=1
    with open(f_name, mode="w") as f:
        f.write("Данные по сайту " + site)
```

В `f.write` соответственно передаете данные с парсинга по сайту.

Через enumerate:

```py
l = ["ya.ru", "google.com", "yandex.ru"]

for i, site in enumerate(l):
    f_name = "site" + str(i) + ".txt"
    print(f_name)
    with open(f_name, mode="w") as f:
        f.write("Данные по сайту " + site)
```

Comment: Специально для такой нумерации в `Python` есть конструкция `enumerate`, чтобы вручную счётчик не вести.

Comment: @CrazyElf добавил вариант с enumerate может кому будет надо.